# jquery.validation plugin duplication of success message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In jquery, using .validation plugin:

```
success:function(span)
{
var fieldname=span.prev().attr("name");
    var message;
    if(fieldname=="lastname")
    {
        message="Nice surname";
    }
span.html("<img src='icons/check.png' />"+message);
}
```

and when I validated, the result is quite great.

[image]

but when I REVALIDATED the form, this is what it looks like

[image]

Is there a code that PREVENTS the duplication and content of an element in jquery?

Comment: Show your complete code for `.validate({})`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because every time `success` fires, you're essentially replacing the default label with your own HTML.  Then the plugin cannot find its original `label` and creates a new one that you again replace with your custom HTML.

The proper way to add/remove images or messages on success/failure is to use the built-in `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions instead.

See this page for documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

More info:

The code in this answer would need to be modified to add/remove your images instead of `class`'s:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15251486/594235

Comment: Yeah you're right in the sense that the original label was being replaced. I'll check first the highlight and unhighlight function. Though I have found a workaround on this problem.